# Which Java IDE is the most RAD in a Delphi-like way?

Tags: java, ide, rad

I want to develop Java apps, real quick, what IDE should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think CodeGear [jbuilder](http://www.codegear.com/products/jbuilder) is a very good start.

Answer (score 5):

[IntelliJ IDEA.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) from JetBrains.

Comment: I love Intellij IDEA but I wouldn't say RAD tool

Answer (score 5):

That depends on which type of developer you are. You the "emacs" (powerful tool) or the "vi" (get things done) type? I, for example, won't touch IntelliJ IDEA even if I was paid for it (and I am). It just gets in my way. I'm an Eclipse guy. Other people can't stand anything besides NetBeans.

I suggest to download IntelliJ, Eclipse and NetBeans and give each a go. Take one day with each, write a piece of code and see how it fits you. Do you get around? Or does the IDE get in the way? Can you quickly find what you seek or are you drowned in options? Does the ride feel smooth or bumpy? Do the defaults match your personal preferences?

Comment: The full power of an IDE only becomes clear when you get used to it.
Most have a whole lot of shortcuts that make your live alot easier once you start using them alot. And you dont even need alot of them.

Comment: The things that annoy you most from day #1 won't change much. If you can't find a way to do what you want, it's the wrong tool. If the way it works gets in your way, it's the wrong tool. And the "full power" also gets in your way while you learn to use something. It's just too much.

Comment: The OP's question was about "RAD in a Delphi-like way". I don't think this is a person who wants emacs or vi.

Comment: "RAD" developers are usually the "emacs" type. For an explanation of the two types, see my blog.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean desktop GUI apps? Then NetBeans' GUI builder is alledgedly very good.

For any other class of app, IntelliJ IDEA wins by many miles. Note: it costs money.

Comment: it offers a free trial that you can renew each month

Comment: IntelliJ Idea has also a good GUI builder ( perhaps just a little behind Netbens ) http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/gui_builder.html

Answer (score 1):

For web apps - [IBM RAD](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/application/) - it's based on Eclipse, but contains much more advance features.

Comment: RAD has many problems and usage many resource